# Extract of Bootstrap 3 CSS crashing IE9

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jwplayer

The following page was constantly crashing for me in IE9 on Windows 7:

http://www.studyzone.tv/test1.html

After much testing around, it turns out the line-height line in the Bootstrap 3 CSS File was causing the crash...or at least conflicting with JWPlayer somehow, and between them, causing the crash!

```
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;  /* THIS IS THE LINE THAT CUASES THE ERROR*/
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

I have duplicated the CSS file and commented the line out and it fixes the problem, as can be seen in this link:

http://www.studyzone.tv/test2.html

I suppose I have two questions:

1. Why is this line causing the crash? Have I really found the problem, or do I have a conflict somewhere else?
2. How can I fix the issue without commenting out the original CSS file which is obviously bad practice?

Comment: For me it always used to be Helvetica to crash bootstrap on IE.

Now, I don't know why, but the workaround would be a style attribute in the document itself, *after* the CSS file (I think, unless it crashes the moment the browsers reads that line, so you should run a test).

Comment: Have you tried using fewer decimal places for the line-height?

Answer (score 2):

It most likely has to do with a clash in HTML5 mode in IE between our HTML5 player and Bootstrap.

You are setting primary to flash inside of the playlist block, so it is never taking effect.

The set up should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("jwplayer").setup({
    playlist: [{
        image: "http://www.studyzone.tv/media/lesson002/lesson002-still.jpg",
        sources: [
            { file: "http://www.studyzone.tv/media/lesson002/lesson002-lq.mp4", label: "360p" },
            { file: "http://www.studyzone.tv/media/lesson002/lesson002-hq.mp4", label: "720p HD" }
        ],
        title: "Play video"
    }],
    width: "700",
    aspectratio: "16:9",
        primary: "flash"
    });
</script>
```

This should solve the issue and you won't have to comment anything out either.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and for spotting the misplaced primary code. I have rewritten this, but it hasn't fixed the problem. See www.studyzone.tv/test3.html and www.studyzone.tv/test4.html.

Comment: This is now running in Flash mode for me correctly. Do you see any errors in the IE9 console, or does it just hang/free and you can't do anything? When I check this in IE9, it still loads and plays fine.

Comment: I fixed the flash mode. It didn't help the crashing of IE9. Commenting out the line-height code does still fix the problem.

Comment: It must be something between Bootstrap 3 CSS and just our JS embedder in general, just in IE9 though. I will pass this along here, thnak you.